# Access local variables from a different binding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby, you can easily access local variables programmatically by using `local_variables` and `eval`. I would really like to have meta-programming access to these variables using a single method call such as

```
# define a variable in this scope, such as
x = 5
Foo.explore_locals  # inside the Foo#explore_locals method, access x
```

where `Foo` is some external module. The idea is to display and export local variables in a nice way.

What should be inside the `explore_locals` method? Is there any way to make this possible? If absolutely necessary, I guess it could be

```
Foo.explore_locals binding
```

but this is much less elegant for the application I have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame there isn't a built-in way to get the caller's binding. The block trick seems to be the usual answer to this question.

However there is another 'trick' which existed for older 1.8 Ruby versions called `binding_of_caller`. Looks like quix ported it to 1.9. You might want to check that out:

https://github.com/quix/binding_of_caller

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (but it requires extra braces `{}` which I would rather avoid if possible):

```
module Foo
  def self.explore_locals &block
    p block.binding.eval 'local_variables'
  end
end

local_1 = 3
Foo.explore_locals{}  # shows [:local_1, :_]
```