# What is the Ruby equivalent of PHP's compact?

Tags: php, ruby

Given some [local variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/localvars.html), what would be the easiest way to [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) them in Ruby?

```
def foo
  name = 'David'
  age = 25
  role = :director
  ...
  # How would you build this:
  # { :name => 'David', :age => 25, :role => :director }
  # or
  # { 'name' => 'David', 'age' => 25, 'role' => :director }
end
```

In PHP, I can simply do this:

```
$foo = compact('name', 'age', 'role');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589894/access-local-variables-from-a-different-binding-in-ruby

Comment: I am honestly baffled about PHP allowing such aberra..., mmm, unorthodox code. Does `compact` really take local variables by name and access them from within another function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came up with a significant improvement on my original answer. It is cleaner if you inherit from `Binding` itself. The `to_sym` is there because older versions of ruby have `local_variables` as strings.

**instance method**

```
class Binding
  def compact( *args )
    compacted = {}
    locals = eval( "local_variables" ).map( &:to_sym )
    args.each do |arg|
      if locals.include? arg.to_sym
        compacted[arg.to_sym] = eval( arg.to_s ) 
      end 
    end 
    return compacted
  end
end
```

**usage**

```
foo = "bar"
bar = "foo"
binding.compact( "foo" ) # => {:foo=>"bar"}
binding.compact( :bar ) # => {:bar=>"foo"}
```

---

**Original answer**

This is the nearest I could get to a method that behaves like Php's [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) -

**method**

```
def compact( *args, &prok )
  compacted = {}
  args.each do |arg|
    if prok.binding.send( :eval, "local_variables" ).include? arg
      compacted[arg.to_sym] = prok.binding.send( :eval, arg ) 
    end
  end 
  return compacted
end
```

**example usage**

```
foo = "bar"
compact( "foo" ){}
# or
compact( "foo", &proc{} )
```

Its not perfect though, because you have to pass a proc in. I am open to suggestions about how to improve this.

Comment: It seems that you could place `eval` outside of the loop, no?

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant on Bungus' answer, but here's a one-liner that is decidedly uglier, but doesn't extend Binding or anything:

```
foo = :bar
baz = :bin
hash = [:foo, :baz].inject({}) {|h, v| h[v] = eval(v.to_s); h }
# hash => {:baz=>:bin, :foo=>:bar}
```

You can also make it look kinda-sorta like a method call by abusing a block binding - again, a  variant on Bungus' original answer:

```
module Kernel
  def compact(&block)
    args = block.call.map &:to_sym
    lvars = block.binding.send(:eval, "local_variables").map &:to_sym
    (args & lvars).inject({}) do |h, v|
      h[v] = block.binding.send(:eval, v.to_s); h
    end
  end
end

foo = :bar
baz = :bin
compact {[ :foo, :bar, :baz ]}
# {:foo=>:bar, :baz=>:bin}
```

(I'll just tell myself that `{[..]}` is the trash compactor symbol.)

If you use the `binding_of_caller` gem, you can forgo the proc *and* explicit binding all together:

```
require 'binding_of_caller'
module Kernel
  def compact(*args)
    lvars = binding.of_caller(1).send(:eval, "local_variables").map &:to_sym
    (args.map(&:to_sym) & lvars).inject({}) do |h, v|
      h[v] = binding.of_caller(2).send(:eval, v.to_s); h
    end
  end
end

foo = :bar
baz = :bin
compact :foo, :bar, :baz
# {:foo=>:bar, :baz=>:bin}
```

Be warned, it's slow. In production code, you should probably never attempt to do this and instead just keep a hash of values so the programmer who has to maintain this after you doesn't hunt you down and kill you in your sleep.